# Overriding GetHashCode and Equals

Tags: c#, overloading

I'm creating a class to wrap a list of `Mask` and I'd like to know if I'm overriding the `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` correctly.

`Mask` is a wrapper for a `List` of `Point`s. It does implement `IEnumerable<Point>`.

```
public class MaskCollection : IEnumerable<Mask>
    {
        #region Variables

        private List<Mask> masks;

        public int Count { get { return masks.Count; } }

        #endregion

        #region Overrides

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            int hash = 0;

            foreach(Mask mask in masks)
            {
                hash ^= mask.Center.GetHashCode();
            }

            return hash;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;

            if (!(obj is MaskCollection)) return false;

            MaskCollection other = (MaskCollection)obj;
            if (this.Count != other.Count) return false;

            HashSet<Mask> uniqueMasks = new HashSet<Mask>(masks);
            foreach(Mask mask in other)
            {
                if (!uniqueMasks.Contains(mask)) return false;
            }

            return true;
        }


        #endregion
    }
```

And if I am overloading them correctly, can this code be improved? My `Equals()` looks really slow, if they actually are equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This implementation of `Equals` violates the contract of `Equals`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The following statements must be true for all implementations of the
>   `Equals(Object)` method. In the list, `x`, `y`, and `z` represent object
>   references that are not null.
>
> - ...
> - `x.Equals(y)` returns the same value as `y.Equals(x)`.

The problem is with this code

> ```
> HashSet<Mask> uniqueMasks = new HashSet<Mask>(masks);
> foreach(Mask mask in other)
> {
>     if (!uniqueMasks.Contains(mask)) return false;
> }
>
> return true;
> ```

As it's possible that all masks in `other` are in `uniqueMasks`, but `uniqueMasks` contains a mask not in `other` (i.e. `other` \$\subsetneq\$ `uniqueMasks`).

For example, the following code will print `False True`.

```
var x = new MaskCollection(new[] { new Mask(0), new Mask(0) });
var y = new MaskCollection(new[] { new Mask(0), new Mask(1) });
Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y));
Console.WriteLine(y.Equals(x));
```

Given this implementation of `Mask`

```
public class Mask : IEquatable<Mask>
{
    private readonly int center;

    public Mask(int center)
    {
        this.center = center;
    }

    public int Center
    {
        get { return this.center; }
    }

    public bool Equals(Mask other)
    {
        return this.center == other.center;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.center.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

---

You could write

```
return new HashSet<Mask>(masks).SetEquals(other);
```

but I would probably recommend *not* overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals` for this class, if you don't have a good reason to do so.

Comment: Nice! I didn't notice that. Already implemented your solution. Sadly I think I do need, since I intend to use it in HashSets.